# How to delete everything related to a used mac program?

Tags: mac

Is it possible to delete everything related to a mac program that you install by dragging the program from a * .dmg file to the program folder? I have tested some app cleaners (AppCleaner and CleanMyMac) but there is still something somewhere that is not deleted.

I have tested in the following way (note I'am not trying crack anything/any software, this is only in ducation and test purpose to see where files go).

- Installed a trial program without using the internet (to see that it
  does not verify against the internet).
- I have used the program one day according to the program.
- Uninstalled the application with AppCleaner
- Empty trash
- Running CleanMyMac
- Searched for the program in the Library folder (no hits)
- Restarted the computer.
- Downloaded and dragged the program to the Programs folder again.

The program still says I used it one day. How is that possible? Where is this information stored and can you find it. Mac has no registry where things are saved (like Windows)

Again, I know this is something that does not take up any direct space on the computer and I do not want to destroy anything but I want to know how it works.

Answer (score 0):

Some app cleaners are better than others, but none is perfect,
so manually cleaning may still be required.

Per each program that leaves traces on the disk you will need to:

- Search the whole disk for folders or files whose names include the program name
  or the company name
- Look for information or cleaning tools on the product's website
- If the product has a user forum, search for the information or post your question
- Perhaps the product Support guys will answer this question if they can be contacted.

There is no one solution that works for all products, each has to be handled separately.

Comment: If it's using a non-networked trial timer, it's likely saved an invisible file somewhere, with some truly unfathomable name like `.fxwy4302pdq.dat` so you have no hope of tracking it back to the app that created it. Example… https://i.stack.imgur.com/uXCcz.png (note:I know what some of these are, of course, but others… not a clue)